# How do I print out a sentence using linked list in C++?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++.
I want to print out a sentence or at least a word.
I could just use cout<<"hello world";
but I want to use linked list.
Is that possible?

Comment: 1) "_Is that possible?_" Yes. 2) What problems are you having, with it? Please show your efforts, with an explanation on what is not working for you.

Comment: ***Is that possible?*** Yes you could put a sentence in a linked list. I would start with std::list<std::string> list; Then list.push_back("Hello"); list.push_back("World"); for( auto& var : list) { std:: cout << var << " "; }

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way, which uses a linked list and output printing a word or space at a time...

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::list<std::string> words;
  words.push_back("hello");
  words.push_back(" ");
  words.push_back("world");
  for (auto const& word : words) {
    std::cout << word;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```